# Configuring solr to match over punctuation, e.g. 'tshirt' matches 't-shirt'

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm using Solr to index products on a clothing website. At the moment I'm trying to get Solr to match `t-shirt` based on the search term `tshirt`, but I'm a little bit lost as to what filters to I need.

This is the general purpose field type that I'm using to index most fields at the moment:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I tried removing `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` from the index and query analyzers, but it didn't help. Any advice/best practice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to have the [`WordDelimiterFilter`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) further up your chain, and you'll want to use the Whitespace Tokenizer instead. The example on the wiki does just that.

The issue now is that the tokens are split into separate tokens earlier on, and the worddelimeterfilter is only seeing each token by itself. So it sees the `t`, then `shirt` and doesn't really have anything to do.

By using the whitespace tokenizer you'll get the WDF to see "t-shirt", allowing it to generate t, shirt, tshirt, etc.

Use the "Analysis" page under the Solr Admin to see each step in the analysis and what the result is.

Comment: Could you link the wiki article by any chance?

Comment: But I wouldn't want "shirt" to be searched when i search for "tshirt". Any fix for this?

Comment: @Moghira Please ask a new question and add the proper details for what you're indexing, what you're searching and what you want the result to be.